# Hosea 6:2. Are the days in this verse more than 24-hr. days and probably much more?

Tags: prophecy, christology, eschatology, hosea

Hoses 6:2

> After two days will he revive us: in the third day he will raise us up, and we shall live in his sight.

Are the days in this verse 24-hour days and if not how long perhaps are they?

Comment: @agarza. Thank you for the formatting on both recent post.

Comment: It reminds about Jesus’ resurrection on the third day and Esther’s meeting with the King on the third day of fasting.

Comment: @Constantthin Interesting screen name. It begs a second look.

Comment: Just in line with your observation, what would day 2 correlate with. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: If the two verses are combined, we may find what we are looking for. I am still in exploration mode and do not want to comment further.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of poetic language, and symbolic language in the writings of the prophet Hosea. This particular verse attracts the following commentary in this Study Bible, and I simply quote it:

> "After two days" - i.e. two days after this national repentance (see
> ch. 5 vs. 15).
>
> "revive us" - bring us back to life.
>
> "live" - live again in resurrection. Referring to the yet future
> resurrection of the new Israel (see Ezekiel chapter 37), which will
> thus resemble the resurrection of Messiah (1 Corinthians 15:20).
>
> "in his sight" - Heb. = before his face, as their sin had been (see
> ch. 7 vs.2). *The Companion Bible*, p.1215, Zondervan, reprint 1974

There is no clear indication of either literal or symbolic 'days' for the earthly nation of Israel in the time of Hosea.

**EDIT** further to OPs comments:
I have done more research, finding an excellent commentary on the book of Hosea which goes for ***fulfillment in the time of Hosea with 'days' representing a short period of time***. Here is the argument:

> "Though God has torn them, and wounded them, Hosea does not believe
> that the wrath of God is his final word in this situation. If Hosea
> had believed that God's wrath was utterly final at this point, he
> would not be ministering to them at all. Yet Hosea knows that God's
> chastenings are preliminary to his restorations. 'He will heal us...He
> will bandage us.'
>
> 4. Hosea asks them to believe that God's delay will not be unbearable. Many Israelites might be tempted to believe that after such deep
>    sinfulness God would be likely to hold the nation in suffering for a
>    long time. The timing of God's chastisements is in his hands. No one
>    can release themselves from God's disciplinary rebukes. 'Surely God
>    will keep us in suffering for a long time', they might feel. 'Not so!'
>    says Hosea. The interval between repentance and renewal of the nation
>    will not be intolerable. [then vs. 2]
>
> The phrase, *'after two days'* probably denotes a short time. *'On the
> third day'*, as well as being a piece of common Canaanite literary
> style (using an 'n, n + 1' increase of numbers as in Ecclesiastes 11:2
> and elsewhere), also denotes a short period. If they will turn to God,
> their resurrection from spiritual death will not take as long as they
> might think.
>
> The fact that Hosea uses the language of resurrection shows us how
> serious the situation as in Israel... One could say that Israel needs
> healing; one could equally say that Israel needs resurrection. It
> needs quickening from 'its death-like state of rejection from the face
> of God.'" *Hosea*, Michael Eaton, pp.99-100, Christian Focus 1996

I would retract my last sentence before this Edit, if that is in order, for my answer now is, ***Hosea speaks of fulfillment in that era of Israel's history, with 'days' representing a short period of time***

Comment: Thank you for the answer you gave. I agree that no literal fulfillment has taken place biblically or historically for this verse of which I am aware. So doesn't that give rise to considering a future symbolic fulfillment as your referenced verses suggest. Lastly do Gen.49:10 and Math.23: 38-39 seem to relate here to your likeing. Other opinions are appreciated on this topic!

Comment: @RHPclass79 I've added an edit for your main point but Gen.49:10 & Mat.23:38-39 are outside the scope of this question. You would need to post a fresh question for that topic, with Stack Christianity likely being the best site for that.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer by research I conducted on how Hebrews counted the days. It was related to Jesus being risen on the third day when 72 hours did not happen between his death and resurrection.

Rabbi Eleazar ben Azariah, tenth in the generations of Ezra said:

> A day and a night are an Onah ['a portion of time'] and the portion of an Onah is like the whole [J. Talmud, Shabbat 9.3 and b.Talmud, Pesahim 4a].

Keeping this in mind and what 2 Peter 3:8 ESV says

> But do not overlook this one fact, beloved, that with the Lord one day is as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day.

One may understand two uses at least, one as Rabbi Eleazar ben Azariah states and the other more poetic meaning an indefinite period. Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: @ Augustinian23 Thank you for your time. I lean toward the 2nd Peter 3:8 and Psalm 90:4 verses. Welcome to the site. I am a newbe as well.

Comment: Thanks @RHPclass79. Nice to meet you, brother.